# My code is making duplicate copies of 2D array elements. What is wrong in the code?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, 2d

My code basically checks a particular triangle in a 3xn array and orders it in ascending order, triangle by triangle. But the problem I am facing right now is, my code is apparently creating duplicates and overwriting data. Please help me figure out the bug.
  Cheers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
system("cls");
int col;
int d = 30000;
int cons = 1;
A:
cout << endl;
int a[3][40000];//Initializing the array to 0
cout << "enter no. of columns:";//No. of Columns for the 3xN matrix
cin >> col;
int noe = col * 3;//Total No. of Elements

//Code to accept the constant multiplier
cout << "Enter the constant multiplier:";
cin >> cons;

//Code to generate a list of random integers and store it in the array 
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    d--;
    a[j][i] = d;
}

cout << "Elements before sort:" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    cout << a[j][i] << " ";
}

int k = 0;
int e = col - 1;
int temp=0;
int temp1 = 0;//Temporary Storage


clock_t begin, end;
double time_spent;

begin = clock();

//Sorting algorithm 
for (int n = 0; n <= noe*cons; n++)
{



    if (k < col - 2)
    {
        //Sorting Upper Triangle
        //3 row check
        if (a[0][k]>a[0][k + 1])
        {
            temp = a[0][k + 1];
            a[0][k + 1] = a[0][k];
            a[0][k] = temp;
        }

        if (a[1][k] > a[1][k + 1])
        {
            temp = a[1][k + 1];
            a[1][k + 1] = a[1][k];
            a[1][k] = temp;
        }

        if (a[2][k] > a[0][k + 2])
        {
            temp = a[0][k + 2];
            a[0][k + 2] = a[2][k];
            a[2][k] = temp;
        }

        //First Column Check
        {
            if (a[0][k] > a[1][k])
            {
                temp = a[1][k];
                a[1][k] = a[0][k];
                a[0][k] = temp;
            }

            if (a[1][k] > a[2][k])
            {
                temp = a[2][k];
                a[2][k] = a[1][k];
                a[1][k] = temp;
            }

            if (a[0][k] > a[1][k])
            {
                temp = a[1][k];
                a[1][k] = a[0][k];
                a[0][k] = temp;
            }

        }
        //Second Column Check
        {
            if (a[0][k + 1] > a[1][k + 1])
            {
                temp = a[1][k + 1];
                a[1][k + 1] = a[0][k + 1];
                a[0][k + 1] = temp;
            }

            if (a[1][k + 1] > a[0][k + 2])
            {
                temp = a[0][k + 2];
                a[0][k + 2] = a[1][k + 1];
                a[1][k + 1] = temp;
            }

            if (a[0][k + 1] > a[1][k + 1])
            {
                temp = a[1][k + 1];
                a[1][k + 1] = a[0][k + 1];
                a[0][k + 1] = temp;
            }
        }

        //3 Diagonal Checks
        if (a[0][k + 1] < a[1][k])
        {
            temp = a[1][k];
            a[1][k] = a[0][k + 1];
            a[0][k + 1] = temp;
        }
        if (a[2][k] > a[1][k + 1])
        {
            temp = a[1][k + 1];
            a[1][k + 1] = a[2][k];
            a[2][k] = temp;
        }
        if (a[2][k] > a[0][k + 1])
        {
            temp = a[0][k + 1];
            a[0][k + 1] = a[2][k];
            a[2][k] = temp;
        }
        //Upper Triangle Sorted
        k++;
    }
    else k = 0;

    if (e >1)
    {
        //Sorting Lower Triangle
        //3 row check
        if (a[2][e - 2]>a[0][e])
        {
            temp1 = a[0][e];
            a[0][e] = a[2][e - 1];
            a[2][e - 2] = temp1;
        }

        if (a[1][e - 1] > a[1][e])
        {
            temp1 = a[1][e];
            a[1][e] = a[1][e - 1];
            a[1][e - 1] = temp1;
        }

        if (a[2][e - 1] > a[2][e])
        {
            temp1 = a[2][e];
            a[2][e] = a[2][e - 1];
            a[2][e - 1] = temp1;
        }

        //First Column Check
        {
            if (a[2][e - 2] > a[1][e - 1])
            {
                temp1 = a[1][e - 1];
                a[1][e - 1] = a[2][e - 2];
                a[2][e - 2] = temp1;
            }

            if (a[1][e - 1] > a[2][e - 1])
            {
                temp1 = a[2][e - 1];
                a[2][e - 1] = a[1][e - 1];
                a[1][e - 1] = temp1;
            }

            if (a[2][e - 2] > a[1][e - 1])
            {
                temp1 = a[1][e - 1];
                a[1][e - 1] = a[2][e - 2];
                a[2][e - 2] = temp1;
            }

        }

        //Second Column Check
        {
            if (a[0][e] > a[1][e])
            {
                temp1 = a[1][e];
                a[1][e] = a[0][e];
                a[0][e] = temp1;
            }

            if (a[1][e] > a[2][e])
            {
                temp1 = a[2][e];
                a[2][e] = a[1][e];
                a[1][e] = temp1;
            }

            if (a[0][e] > a[1][e])
            {
                temp1 = a[1][e];
                a[1][e] = a[0][e];
                a[0][e] = temp1;
            }
        }

        //3 Diagonal Checks
        if (a[0][e] < a[1][e - 1])
        {
            temp1 = a[1][e - 1];
            a[1][e - 1] = a[0][e];
            a[0][e] = temp1;
        }
        if (a[2][e - 1] > a[1][e])
        {
            temp1 = a[1][e];
            a[1][e] = a[2][e - 1];
            a[2][e - 1] = temp1;
        }
        if (a[2][e - 1] > a[0][e])
        {
            temp1 = a[0][e];
            a[0][e] = a[2][e - 1];
            a[2][e - 1] = temp1;
        }
        //Lower Triangle Sorted
        e--;

    }
    else e = col - 1;



}

end = clock();
time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


//Code to print the sorted elements
cout << "Sorted Elements:" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    cout << a[j][i] << " ";
}

//Code to check if the elements are sorted or not
int l = 0;
int s = a[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
{
    if (s > a[j][i])l++;
    s = a[j][i];
}

if (l == 0)cout << "\nSorted Array!\n";
else cout << "\nUnsorted!\n";

cout << time_spent;
cout << endl;

system("pause");
goto A;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "orders it in ascended order" exactly? Assuming you have X/Y/Z coordinates for triangles it doesn't make much sense to compare and swap between the coordinates of one triangle. At the very least use [`std::swap()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) to make your code much shorter and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! SWAG FUNCTION WORKS LIKE CHARM *_* CHEERS! :D YOU MADE MY DAY!

Comment: Copied comment to answer since it seemed to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your ordering needs but at the very least you should be using [`std::swap()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/) instead of all your manual swaps, like:

```
#include <algorithm>
...

    if (a[0][k] > a[0][k + 1]) std::swap(a[0][k], a[0][k + 1]);
```

It will make your code much shorter, easier to read, and more importantly fix any mistakes in your manual swaps. It is far too easy to get an index wrong and far to hard to spot it.